# Federated authentication (single-sign-on) for a WCF REST/HTML-service on Azure

Tags: wcf, azure, federated-identity

I have made a simple WCF-REST-service, published it to Azure and activated SSL with a X.509-certificate.

I'd like to setup some authentication for this service as well. I could solve this very easily by sending a credentials-header in clear text since all traffic is now encrypted, but I am planning to use some kind of federated authentication instead so that users can take advantage of Single Sign-On.

This field is relatively new and yet seems to already be littered with obsolete technology, making it difficult for someone with little experience to find current best practices and solid toolsets. I'm hoping somebody with significant experience can provide some insight and give us all an up-to-date jumpstart.

#### What are the modern, state-of-the-art options for federated authentication?

Is OpenId the only technology for this?

#### Is it difficult to implement SSO?

Can a relatively inexperienced yet reasonably intelligent developer implement this based off a few tutorials? Or are the underlying technologies too complex, making a third-party API/framework more desirable? (like DotNetOpenAuth)

For Azure and WCF specifically, is "Windows Azure Active Directory Access Control" really necessary, or would that be like swatting a fly with a sledgehammer?

Comment: We use ADFS (Active Directory Federated Services) for this. Right now, we host the AD and ADFS on-premise but with these recent Active Directory/Azure announcements, I think we could possibly move that all up to Azure now. With ADFS, you can get passive federation for your websites while using active federation for your web services clients (we use WCF).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Authentication, Authorization and identity federation are **HUGELY** complex subjects and should not be taken lightly. The reason security is a big, complex problem is that its extraordinarily hard to get right!

If you don't already have a great deal of experience in internet identity & security, **don't try and roll your own auth mechanism**: Correctly and securely implementing an authentication mechanism is very, VERY hard.

For example, in your scenario above, you've not accounted for ensuring that the creds you pass in the HTTP header are anonymized for each site you want to present them to and that they expire after a period of time, that they cannot be replayed, that they cannot be synthesized by a malicious 3rd party, etc.

I **strongly** encourage you to use a pre-existing authn mechanism and supporting framework. In fact, since you're an Azure user, the easiest way to add end-user identity federation to your site is to use the [new authn features of Windows Azure Mobile Services](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/mobile/tutorials/get-started-with-users-dotnet/)

If you still want to learn more about identity and identity federation, I encourage you to research this subject before choosing the right type of authentication to use:

Start with [A Guide to Claims-Based Identity and Access Control (2nd Edition)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff423674.aspx). This will give you most of the background and knowledge necessary to understand this subject sufficiently to make sound decisions.

Once you've got a good grip on this subject, I recommend reading everything that Vittorio Bertocci has written over at http://cloudidentity.com.

HTH.

Comment: +1 for the "don't try and roll your own auth mechanism."  Same idea as anybody who tries to roll almost anything security-related: it's too easy to get it wrong.  Sometimes even using what's out there "right" is enough of a challenge.