# Windows Azure Active directory for WCF Rest API Or OAuth Provider

Tags: wcf, azure, active-directory, azure-active-directory

I have build simple web service using WCF that i need to Authenticate against Windows Azure Active directory. What i need is When some one use the service they have enter username and password or secret key then validate against the Azure AD. Could some one direct me with any tutorial or Sample.
I have looked into [Federated authentication (single-sign-on) for a WCF REST/HTML-service on Azure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16241232/federated-authentication-single-sign-on-for-a-wcf-rest-html-service-on-azure) and [Azure WCF Service with Azure Active Directory Authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16403426/azure-wcf-service-with-azure-active-directory-authentication)
didn't help me.

Thanks In advance.